# What does "promotional credit" mean?

Tags: meaning

Source: [How a prodigy built a billion-dollar empire from age 14](http://www.cnbc.com/2017/05/25/how-greensky-billionaire-david-zalik-built-a-tech-empire-from-age-14.html)

> "We work with 17,000 merchant retailers ... to offer instant promotional credit to now over 1.2 million consumer customers," Zalik told CNBC.

I googled it but I couldn't find any results. Does it mean "cheap credit" or "discounted credit"?

OALD: [promotional](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/promotional?q=promotional+)

Comment: What do you mean by _"I googled it"?_  What exactly did you do when you _googled?_ This phrase is no more difficult than the phrase _brown horse._ Are you familiar with the adjective _promotional_ and the noun _credit?_  What kind of _credit_ is it? It is _promotional._ I recommend that you _dictionary_ these words instead of _googling_ them.

Comment: There is no such kind of credit in my country. So it's normal when I don't know.

Comment: Already, @P.E.Dant. I attached the link in my question.

Comment: I am baffled. If you know what a _credit_ is, and you know what the adjective _promotional_ means, what is it that you don't understand about the phrase _promotional credit?_ If you know what a _horse_ is, and you know what the adjective _brown_ means, do you understand the phrase _brown horse?_

Comment: In what context is "*promotional credit*" being used? Do you have a link to the original text, it could have different meanings depending on context.

Comment: "We work with 17,000 merchant retailers ... to offer instant promotional credit to now over 1.2 million consumer customers," Zalik told CNBC. http://www.cnbc.com/2017/05/25/how-greensky-billionaire-david-zalik-built-a-tech-empire-from-age-14.html

Comment: @P.E.Dant: In my mother tongue, "promotional means you will get a gift or some money for the stuff you buy and credit means the money you borrow from a lender". So that's the reason why I got confused by their combination "you borrow some money and you will get some more money as a gift from a lender?"

Comment: Browbeating questioners is unlikely to help them learn. I'm a native English speaker, and without context, it's not entirely clear to me what "promotional credit" necessarily means. I could make some guesses, but context matters.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs yes, I too find the remarks patronising and objectionable.

Comment: @WS2: It's not that bad. I just find him objectionable, not patronising.

Comment: For the record, @haile has a long history of asking questions here which show little or no effort on his part to consult a dictionary, and when consulting a dictionary, it is rarely one of the ones which offer a wide range of definitions and example sentences. This has been brought to the OP's attention on multiple occasions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "credit" has several senses in English. It appears that, in this case, "credit" is being used to mean, "entitlement to a set amount of a particular company's goods or services, typically paid for in advance of use." (See, for example, [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+credit&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS743US743&oq=define+credit&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3151j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), under #2, if you click to expand the basic definitions supplied by Google.)

Thus, as a promotion (as a marketing tool), these retailers are offering some entitlement to their goods or services, without the customer having to make a payment for the privilege.

Suppose I open a new store. Then, to attract attention, I print and distribute certificates that say, "this certificate entitles the bearer to $5 towards a purchase at my new store," that would be a promotional credit.